# Why on iPad inline CSS rules override !important

Tags: css, ipad, css-selectors

Normally the !important declaration overrides normal declarations.

But on iPad I found that my CSS rule !important was overriden by inline CSS rules (added with javascript)

[image]

(I checked on Safari with Mac I don't have this problem, neither with an Android tablet )

Do someone know why ?

Edit: My problem is that I have a twitter widget on my page, with an iPad when I switch from portrait to landscape: the widget stay at the portrait size

[image]

Comment: Your question is much more likely to get an answer if you make a test case/demo that shows the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot i added screen capture of my problem, does it help ? or maybe you were thinking of a jsfiddle ?

Comment: It helps a bit, but I really meant https://jsfiddle.net/ etc. A live test page showing the issue is needed to debug it. Otherwise, someone must either try to make a test case themselves (too much work), or they must already know the answer (unlikely).

Comment: Are you sure you're inspecting the right pieces of the DOM? Can you provide a larger image or more complete example? The `element.style` says `width: 520px;` but the inline style that is highlighted is showing both `width: 520px` *and* `width: 180px;`. But the rest of the text is cut-off.

Comment: I believe the **inline styles** will overwrite any(including **!important**) other CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a CSS sheet, you put all the style information once, at first. 
If you add or modify an element using javascript or jquery, it will add the new rule, because it overwrites everything.